# Error reading string with cin

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I have a silly mistake , but managed not find it is. On line 17 I try to read two integers and a string, but when I input (or similar):

```
2 3 (
```

I keep being asked entries. When I input (or similar):

```
2 3 F
```

reads smoothly. Could it be " ( " a special character ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ocurs(string cad, string subcad) {
    int con = -1;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(i != string::npos) {
        i = cad.find(subcad, i);
        con++;
    }
    return con;
}

int main() {
    int n, m, con = 0;
    string cad, subcad;
    cin >> n >> m >> subcad;
    //cout << subcad;
    for(int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
        cad.push_back('(');
    for(int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
       cad.push_back(')');
    //cout << cad;
    con += ocurs(cad, subcad);
    cad.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(i % 2 == 0) cad.push_back('(');
        else cad.push_back(')');
    con += ocurs(cad, subcad);
    cout << con;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing that asks for data entry except line 17 and no loops around it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to run a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You end up in an endless loop inside `ocurs()`, because when `cad.find()` finds the sought substring, you feed it with the same index it returns, and it keeps finding the same substring.  You need to fix your `ocurs()` routine, for example by adding

```
if (i != string::npos) ++i;
```

after the `find` statement.

The broader answer is that you should learn to use a debugger – or, at least, use some more `cout` statements where they might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.